# Cant find package for wireless network card, Arch-linux

Tags: arch-linux, network-interface, broadcom

I'm trying to install the wireless driver for my network card. The Wireless Linux Wiki says that I need to install the b43 driver since my card is [listed there](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#list_of_hardware).

I'm on arch linux. I've installed it multiple times, but I seem to never be able to get the wireless network working.

I've tried installing form both arch-chroot and the root user (after booting)

I can't find the package the though

```
pacman -S b43-firmware
```

keeps getting the error "no target found". Any suggestions?
Thanks.
Output from "uname -a"

```
uname -a
Linux arches 4.5-4-1-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Wed May 22:21:28 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output from "lspci -vnn -d 14e4:"

```
[root@archiso /]#lspci -vnn -d 14e4:
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5761 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:43959]

Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0014]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at f7e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 (?)
Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-84-ff-ff-7c-1c-3e
Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
```

Output from "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2"
`[root@archiso /]#lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

lspci: no such PCI access method:2 (see`-A help for a list)`

Comment: Please edit and add the output of `uname -a` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Please edit and verify `[14e4:43959]` isn't correct , the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` will give you more details.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the b43-firmware package is kept within the AUR, the Arch User Repository. For how to install packages from the AUR, you should check the Arch wiki. Note that for an AUR helper, yay is suggested because most others are unmaintained. Secondly, the command "pacman -Ss" searches packages as opposed to "pacman -S", which installs packages. Finally, you should check if b43-firmware or b43-firmware-classic better supports your card as can be found on the Broadcom Arch wiki page. The third point has caused me trouble before.